# About Firebase Flame Plan Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storage

Is the 50 GB storage mentioned in firebase flame plan updated monthly like we get 50 GB every month or Is it like 50 GB only, after that we cannot use it or upload files to storage.

Answer (score 0):

For storage, the 50MB limit for GB stored, as shown on the [pricing page](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/558#issuecomment-372058769) is a hard limit for the total amount of storage used at any give time.  You don't accumulate more storage limits every month.  On that billing page, you will know which limits are daily or monthly because the measurement will explicitly say "/day" (per day) or "/month" (per month).